# android studio: gradle: build never ends, Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am trying to get my android studio to work again like it did a couple of weeks ago. 
Unfortunately it keeps giving me errors. When I run the software gradle will automatically start to refresh my project I imported from eclipse. 
It stays on the message "Gradle: Build".
When I look in the gradle log files I see the error

> org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

I have tried turning of my firewall and antivirus which was suggested in the few posts I found on the subject to no avail.
Anyone any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: my os is win 7 64bit

Comment: Had the same problem, this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28655193/2456238) has helped me to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

---

> Try upgrading and degradink jdk/jre versions

---

Comment: You should use comment for short answer or proposition of solution.